# grep most recent entry across multiple log files

Tags: matlab, unix, logging, grep

I'm running a job array in MATLAB which is essentially two nested FOR loops but across 60 nodes (i.e. 60 log files) simultaneously. I'd like to be able to get the status of all jobs simultaneously. 
Each log file outputs "index1=1 of 100" for the outer loop, and "index2=1 of X" where X is variable, sometimes 100, sometimes 60,000. What I want to know is the status of index1.

```
> grep index1 *.out
```

dumps everything across all log files.

```
> tail -n 100 | grep index1 *.out
```

is better but if X is big, it gets nothing and if X is small gets too much output. 
Pseudo code of what I think I need:

1. Grep index1 across all files (keeping file names somehow)
2. Only keep last entry per file
3. Output into STDOUT or file

Note: I've written the MATLAB code so I could also change the structure/appearance of the log file entries to make this easier.

Comment: If each line of each log had index1  AND index2 written on it, then a simple tail -5 *.out | sort | tail    will give you what you want.

Comment: jim - that looks like it will work also, but the job is running now and will take a few days. I'll try it next time when I can edit my log entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to now number filenames try:

```
for file in *.out; do grep -H index1 $file | tail -n 1; done
```

or if you don't needed:

```
for file in *.out; do grep index1 $file | tail -n 1; done
```